# Generators of $GL_2(\mathbb Q) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can anybody help me with following problem, please? I have to show that   $$GL_2(\mathbb Q) = \left<
\begin{bmatrix} 
   a& 0 \\
    0      & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 0 \\
    0      & a \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 1 \\
    0      & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 0 \\
    1      & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}: a \in \mathbb Q \setminus \{0\}
\right>,
$$
but no idea here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Any matrix in $\mathbf{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ is equivalent under elementary row operations to the identity matrix. Recall how row reduction is related to [elementary matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix) and observe that all the proposed generators are indeed elementary matrices.